# Custom permalink for each post

Tags: posts, permalinks, post-meta, guids

im importing data from Drupal to WP. I have more than 10 000 posts. Each post have ID, category and slug. For example:

- Category> **important**
- ID> **11111**
- Slug> **hello-world**

I need to keep permalinks same like they are on drupal because of SEO:

> www.wordpress.com/important/11111-hello-world

The problem is that, i cant insert post with ID 11111 until is database index set to this number. If i do import, this post will actually much smaller, never the same like on drupal.

I wanted to make post-meta with old url. For example

- _oldSlug> **11111-hello-world**

And then apply rule: If is set post-meta named "_oldSlug" use it `(%category%/_oldSlug)`, else use wp logic `(%category%/%postid%-%postname%)`.
But problem is, that i dont know how to achieve it, if is that posible...

Any idea how solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Migrating content from Drupal to WordPress is bit tricky task and requires expertise. If you are familiar with WordPress development, try to find some solution around "save_posts" hook which will get triggered whenever new post/page gets saved into database. Before you jump into actual coding, I suggest you to take a look at these articles, to get more understanding about Drupal to WordPress migration.

[From Drupal To WordPress](https://www.wpmayor.com/drupal-wordpress-conversion/)

[How To Migrate From Drupal To Wordpress](http://www.i4u.com/2016/04/108319/how-migrate-drupal-wordpress)

Comment: Please add the important contents from the link to your answer instead of just posting links

Comment: Sure thing. I will keep this advice in mind when I post any answer now onwards. Thanks for the advice. :)